# How  to group data in  datatable in c#

Tags: c#

I have a datatable like this(I am getting the data from an excel sheet).
I am converting the excel sheet  to a datatable. Now i need to format the data.
This is what my datatable looks like.

```
Lead    EMPnames
vinay    kumar
vinay    manju.u
vinay    kiran
anitha   manju.k
anitha   rahul
sandeep  arjun
sandeep  manu
rohit     sandeep
rohit     vinay
rohit     anitha
```

Now I need  to format the datatable like this :

```
Lead     EMPnames
vinay    kumar
         manju.u
         kiran
sandeep  arjun
         manu
anitha   manju.k
         rahul
rohit    sandeep
         vinay
         anitha
```

Any idea as  how  to do this? 
Any help would be appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with formatting? Formatting it to the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use linq with the "group by" clause?

For example please see the sample 3 in the following link :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1

Comment: Just to keep things up-to-date, the above link now redirects to general 101 LINQ. That is why it is always better to also show code samples in an answer rather than just posting a link. To find the code pointed out by the old link, go to the grouping section and click any of the samples listed there.

Answer (score 0):

We have take the lead names in an array.

```
string[] srLead = { "vinay", "sandeep", "anitha", "rohit" };
```

then take the source datatable and filter it based on the  lead names  and  add  to a new  DataTable:

```
    #region Grouping by Teamlead
    DataTable dtGroup = new DataTable();
    dtGroup = dtResult.Clone();
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dtResult.Columns)
    {
        dc.DataType = typeof(string);
    }
    dtGroup.AcceptChanges();

    foreach (string s in srLead)
    {
        string name = s;
        DataTable dtsource = new DataTable();
        dtsource = TeamLeadFilter(dtResult, name);
        CombineDatatable(ref dtGroup, dtsource);
        dtGroup.AcceptChanges();
    }
    #endregion

    #region TeamLeadFilter
    public DataTable TeamLeadFilter(DataTable dtResult, string str)
    {
        DataView dvData = new DataView(dtResult);
        dvData.RowFilter = "TeamLead ='" + str + "'";
        return dvData.ToTable();
    }
    #endregion

    #region CombineDatatable
    public DataTable CombineDatatable(ref DataTable destini, DataTable source)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in source.Rows)
        {
            destini.ImportRow(dr);
        }
        return destini;
    }
    #endregion
```

by this way i solved  the issue.